# Unable to initilaize hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

**I am trying to migrate the spring application to spring boot. While migrating am getting an error related to hibernate**

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/SpringBeanContainer

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:132) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_271]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringBeanContainer
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)

[image]

Comment: The error is `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringBeanContainer`, you're probably missing some jars

Comment: @Guillaume Yes you were correct I was using the wrong dependency version of spring ORM. Can you help me @PersistanceContext(unitName="batch") am trying to use it. But it gives an error "A component required a bean named 'batch' that could not be found." I have defined this in .XML file

Comment: is that xml file is being picked up by the configurations while setting up the spring boot application at startup, seems not please look into that

Comment: In the above screenshot the name is "batchDS" not "batch"

Comment: @Guillaume Sorry i typed it wrong am using batchDS only

Comment: @anishsharma Can you help me like how can i check this file being used or not at startup?

Comment: try adding this in your springboot main class  @ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"}) replace the xml file name with your xml file name